# Finding the kernel , the image and the rank of $[A\ A]$ for an invertible $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, mathematical-physics

Let $A$ be an invertible matrix of order $n$. What are the kernel, the image, and the rank of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} A & A \end{bmatrix}$ (of order $n \times 2n$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\begin{bmatrix} A & A \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ x \end{bmatrix} = Ax + Ax = 2Ax.$$

Comment: how about image and rank?

Comment: Since $A$ is invertible, for every $y$ there is an $x$ such that $Ax = y$. Here, you have the same domain, so... :-) And once you see the image, you have the rank as well. However, be careful with the kernel. $[x\ x]^T$ is not the only kind of vectors. The kernel has dimension $n$. In case you cannot see why, please ask.

Comment: if for every $y$ there is $Ax=y$  $a$ must be full ranked and the rank of $[AA]$ is equal to rank of $[A]$.i think

Comment: Yes, it is. Also, the image is the same as the image of $A$. Now, the kernel?